# Riak CS - Unable to create/view bucket details using dragon disk

Tags: riak, riak-cs

I installed Riak 2.0.5, Riak-cs 2.0.1(AWS VM) and trying to access it from Dragon disk. I ran s3cmd --configure and set the access/secret key. But unable to view Riak bucket details in Dragon Disk using access/secret key. I'm able to view/post data using Rest API client.

Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: by Rest API, you mean the Riak instance like `http://host:8098/buckets/bucket/props`?  Have you tried uploading a file with d3cmd?

Comment: Hey Joe, I'm unable to upload a file using s3cmd. But able to access through rest api. Output of http://host:8098/buckets/bucket/props                      {
props: {
name: "bucket"
allow_mult: true
basic_quorum: false
big_vclock: 50
chash_keyfun: {
mod: "riak_core_util"
fun: "chash_std_keyfun"
}-
dvv_enabled: false
dw: "quorum"
last_write_wins: false
linkfun: {
mod: "riak_kv_wm_link_walker"
fun: "mapreduce_linkfun"
}-
n_val: 3
notfound_ok: true
old_vclock: 86400
postcommit: [0]
pr: 0
precommit: [0]
pw: 0
r: "quorum"
rw: "quorum"
small_vclock: 50
w: "quorum"
young_vclock: 20
}-
} ---- G

Comment: so Riak is running, is Riak CS running? Does it answer on the port you configured (default 8080)? Is there a hostname or proxy configuration in Dragon Disk that needs to be set?

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't try to communicate with riak itself (port 8089). All communications must be thru Riak-CS (port 8080)!

Then try to success using s3cmd:

Give us content of your `.s3cfg` file?
In your case the minimum config is:

```
[default]
access_key = KEY
secret_key = SECRET
host_base = <root_host from riak-cs.conf>
host_bucket = %(bucket)s.<root_host from riak-cs.conf>
proxy_host = <ip of any cluster node>
proxy_port = 8080
```

Please be sure you use proxy_host -it should not be blank and should be ip address of one of Riak-CS cluster nodes. Otherwise s3cmd will try to resolve hostneme from `host_base` and connect to it using http via tcp port 80 which is probably not what you want.

After you succeed with s3cmd you can go farther and show us Dragon Disk Account configuration, I'll tell you what's wrong with it.